# How to get the number of exception the service has encountered in WCF?

Tags: wcf, exception, behavior, dispatcher

How will I be able to count the number of exceptions thrown during the execution of a service?
Right now I'm using behaviors to hook with the dispatchers using IOperationInvoker and IParameterInspector. But I need to know how can i count the faults and exceptions that occurs in a particular operation or the total occurrence in the whole service.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of approaches exist. You can use tracing (and inspect your log files); through instrumentation, that is, use performance counters to monitor faults on services or operations.

A nice way of achieving service monitoring is also available through AppFabric, if this is available to you.

HTH